# Circle & Triangle segment lengths (AMC 10A 2013 #23)

Tags: geometry

I've been struggling with a problem for a long time today: 
*In $\triangle ABC$, $AB = 86$, and $AC=97$. A circle with center $A$ and radius $AB$ intersects $\overline{BC}$ at points $B$ and $X$. Moreover $\overline{BX}$ and $\overline{CX}$ have integer lengths. What is $BC$?*

My method:
1. I constructed segment DX in the hopes of creating similar triangle ABC & DXC, but these similar triangles produce decimal lengths for BX & XC. I'm also aware of the theorem that DC(AD*DC) = XC(BX+XC), but this doesn't seem to take me anywhere.

For context:
[Method I Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9h3t2.png)

Comment: A solution can be found at the following link:
$$$$
$\qquad$https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=2013_AMC_10A_Problems/Problem_23
$$$$

Comment: Thank you, but I still don't understand why my method is wrong.

Comment: the triangles you speak of are **not** similar! If you extend AC until it meets the circle again, then you will have similar triangles. The theorem you are trying to apply is a corollary of the similarity you are trying to invoke, but again, you are applying it incorrectly. The segments that are multiplied extend from the common point ($C$) to points **on the circle.** $A$ is not on the circle.

Comment: Right, but how do you utilize power of points to arrive at the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take point $D$ on $AC$ such that $AD=AB=86$. Point $D$ is then on the circle and:
$$
CB\cdot CX=CD(CD+2AD)=11\cdot183=33\cdot61.
$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be CD * (CD+AD), instead of CD(CD+2AD)? Why the 2AD? Thank you.

Comment: Because if you produce $CA$ to meet again the circle at $E$, then $DE$ is a diameter and $CE=CD+DE=CD+2AD$.